# Depth Map of a Sculpt

Tags: rendering, sculpting, depth-map

I have sculpted a model in Sculpt mode within Blender. It model has:

1. Not been Rendered
2. Not been retopologized
3. 2 million vertices
4. 2 million faces.
5. need to be rigged, 3d printed or animated.

I'm new to 3D (just been watching tutorials).

I want to create a very detailed (or perhaps the term might be "high resolution") depth map of this model.

Would I need to Retopologize it first?
If I need to Render it first before I use Blender to make a depth map, is there a specific manner in which in needs to be rendered in order to bring the most optimal results in my depth map?

Comment: Hello, by "depth map" do you mean "bump" or "height map"? If you plan to print the object, you need a high resolution object, no need for a bump map, if you plan to use it in a 3D scene and even more if you plan to rig or animate it, you need a low-poly version with much less vertices, then bake the high-poly version to get the bump map in order to recreate fake 3D details on the low-poly version, but I may have not understood your question correctly?

Comment: Yes i do think what i am referring to is a height map. I do not plan to print or animate the object. And...I have been successful in creating a depth map now in Blender. The problem that i have...is it is too contrasty. Even with adjusting the gamma. In this sense, it requires me to do a lot of tweaking in photoshop to make it useable. I am looking to adjust setting on the front end in order to avoid make adjustments on the back end. My goal is to make a depth map that accurately portrays the depth...not create the extreme contrast between White and black.